# Error when migrating wordpress site from subfolder to root folder

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I'm seeing in the browser, after going through the steps at http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website/

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in /home4/brycepj/public_html/index.php on line 17

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home4/brycepj/public_html/index.php on line 17

Here's the code from the relevant file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require ('./dev/wp-blog-header.php);
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just missing an apostrophe after the wp-blog-header.php --- if you're using Smashing Magazine's tutorial, this is your problem. I copy and pasted directly from their post.

Comment: You should use `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`.  `wp-blog-header.php` might make your pages return a 404 status even though they don't display as 404's

Comment: @Nick, This is default `index.php` I think.

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking this was a self made file not the default index file. I was wrong.